# Timeout connection Mysql in fuelPHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fuelphp

I just wonder where the timeout_connection (MySQL) are set in Fuelphp framework? Because I can't see the information. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

timeout_connection is in php.ini, you could try with this:

Check your timeout:

```
echo ini_get('mysql.connect_timeout');
```

You could change it with:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',100);
```

Where "100" is the number of milliseconds